# What are the possible options for the Appearance option of IntervalSlider?

Tags: graphics, style, gui-construction

`IntervalSlider` has a styling option `Appearance -> ...`, where possible options include `"ThumbAppearance"` which allow one to change the styling of the little drag handles as shown below.

How can I find what other valid options there are? For example I wish to change the blue shading of the interval to red.

```
IntervalSlider[Dynamic[int], {0, 100, 1}, 
 Appearance -> {"ThumbAppearance" -> {
  Dynamic[Framed[First[int], Background -> LightPurple]], 
  None, 
  Dynamic[Framed[Last[int], Background -> LightPurple]]}}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: An analogous `ThumbAppearance` option for `Slider` would also be useful.